# unable to increase height of form in visual studio .net 3.5 

Tags: visual-studio

I am unable to increase height of a form in Visual Studio 2008. It goes up to 812 pixels but not beyond that!

If I set it to 813 it goes back to 812.

Comment: Have you set a MaxHeight ? BTW, you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make the form larger than your screen.  812 sounds about right for a something x 800 screen resolution + borders, a pretty common resolution on LCD panels with Aero fat borders enabled.  This is Winforms trying to make you do the right thing by not creating a window that's hostile to the user.  Who has very few options to move the window so that the bottom part is visible.  Dragging the caption won't work, she can't drag it beyond the top desktop edge.  Only the system menu can make it visible, very unlikely that your user will stumble on that solution.

Make it usable by setting the form's AutoScroll property to True.